# From a single line to a list (Loop)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to reconfigure VBA code so that it goes through a list instead of a single line of my list.

Currently the code works exactly the way I want it to but I am having trouble figuring out the loop so that it processes the whole list for me.

Do you have any suggestions? Code below [Code attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Y93.png)

**EDIT:**

```
Sub sbCopyingAFileReadFromSheet()

'Declaration
Dim FSO
Dim sFile As String
Dim sSFolder As String
Dim sDFolder As String
Dim sFilenew As String


'This is Your File Name which you want to Copy.You can change File name at B5.
sFile = Sheets("Main").Range("F5")

'Change to match the source folder path. You can change Source Folder name at B6.
sSFolder = Sheets("Main").Range("B5")

'Change to match the destination folder path. You can change Destination Folder name at B6.
sDFolder = Sheets("Main").Range("C5")

'Change name to new file name.
sFilenew = Sheets("Main").Range("D5")

'Create Object for File System
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Checking If File Is Located in the Source Folder
If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
    MsgBox "Specified File Not Found in Source Folder Error 2", vbInformation, "Not Found"

'Copying If the Same File is Not Located in the Destination Folder
ElseIf Not FSO.FileExists(sDFolder & sFile) Then
    FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), (sDFolder & sFilenew), True
    MsgBox "Specified File Copied to Destination Folder Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"
Else
    MsgBox "Specified File Already Exists In The Destination Folder", vbExclamation, "File Already Exists"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Seriously dude a picture, why are you making harder on us to help you out

Comment: @0m3r fair call, sorry for the rookie error. I have updated it with the actual text code. Is that more suitable?

Comment: What are you trying to do that will require a loop? If you're talking this entire subroutine, put all of the code within a While/Wend loop probably with a condition of: While sFile <> "", and set sFile to something outside the loop so that it goes through once.

Comment: Unrelated: Every type you type `sFile = Sheets("Main").Range("F5")` there an implied `.Value` property used. In order to make it clear that you assign a value and not a range object try to include it, as in `sFile = Sheets("Main").Range("F5").Value`. Better yet, use `.Value2` which handles dates better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Do Until IsEmpty loop, easy to understand.

```
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    iRow = 5 ' start from row 5
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- update sheet name

        Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(iRow, 6)) ' (Row, Column)
            sFile = .Cells(iRow, 6).Value
            sSFolder = .Cells(iRow, 2).Value
            sDFolder = .Cells(iRow, 3).Value
            sFilenew = .Cells(iRow, 4).Value

            'Checking If File Is Located in the Source Folder
            If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
                Debug.Print "Specified File Not Found in Source Folder Error 2", vbInformation, "Not Found" 'Print on Immediate
'                MsgBox "Specified File Not Found in Source Folder Error 2", vbInformation, "Not Found"

            'Copying If the Same File is Not Located in the Destination Folder
            ElseIf Not FSO.FileExists(sDFolder & sFile) Then
                FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), (sDFolder & sFilenew), True
'                MsgBox "Specified File Copied to Destination Folder Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"
                Debug.Print "Specified File Copied to Destination Folder Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"  'Print on Immediate
            Else
'                MsgBox "Specified File Already Exists In The Destination Folder", vbExclamation, "File Already Exists"
                Debug.Print "Specified File Already Exists In The Destination Folder", vbExclamation, "File Already Exists"  'Print on Immediate
            End If

            iRow = iRow + 1
        Loop
    End With
```

Comment: Hey @0m3r - I have run that code but I am unable to get it to work due to these errors. I know they are basic errors but my reading so far hasn't helped me debug them. I am getting a Expected End Sub, because I have put a Sub sbCopyingAFIle() at the top so that I can name the function.

Comment: It says Compile error" Expected End Sub and then highlights the 1st line, which has Sub sbCopyingaFile() in it. Sorry again, I imagine the answer is fairly elementary.

Comment: 0m3r - Thank you so much for the help. It works flawlessly !

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub sbCopyingAFileReadFromSheet()

'Declaration
Dim FSO
Dim sFile As String
Dim sSFolder As String
Dim sDFolder As String
Dim sFilenew As String
Dim i As Long, Lr As Long

    'Create Object for File System
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Lr = 10 'Change this to your needs
    For i = 5 To Lr
        'This is Your File Name which you want to Copy.You can change File name at B5.
        sFile = Sheets("Main").Range("F" & i)

        'Change to match the source folder path. You can change Source Folder name at B6.
        sSFolder = Sheets("Main").Range("B" & i)

        'Change to match the destination folder path. You can change Destination Folder name at B6.
        sDFolder = Sheets("Main").Range("C" & i)

        'Change name to new file name.
        sFilenew = Sheets("Main").Range("D" & i)

        'Checking If File Is Located in the Source Folder
        If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
            MsgBox "Specified File Not Found in Source Folder Error 2", vbInformation, "Not Found"

        'Copying If the Same File is Not Located in the Destination Folder
        ElseIf Not FSO.FileExists(sDFolder & sFile) Then
            FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), (sDFolder & sFilenew), True
            MsgBox "Specified File Copied to Destination Folder Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"
        Else
            MsgBox "Specified File Already Exists In The Destination Folder", vbExclamation, "File Already Exists"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Better to set sFile = "x" and then use a While sFile <> "" (insert code here) Wend. Using a For loop will require a change every time you decide you need a different number of iterations.

Comment: Thank you @PKatona, if this is needed we can simply add `if sFile = "" then exit for`